# What is the difference between end() and endChoice() in Apache Camel

Tags: apache-camel

Can anyone tell me the difference between `end()` and `endChoice()` in camel? Can we use `end()` in place of `endChoice()`?

Comment: Read the javadoc of those methods

Answer (score 15):

The `endChoice()` has quite an unfortunate naming. It doesn't end the `choice()` block, it just ends the current `when()` clause.

`end()` on the other hand closes the current `choice()` block.

Can also be seen in the javadocs:

- [endChoice](https://static.javadoc.io/org.apache.camel/camel-core/2.22.1/org/apache/camel/model/ProcessorDefinition.html#endChoice--)
- [end](https://static.javadoc.io/org.apache.camel/camel-core/2.22.1/org/apache/camel/model/ProcessorDefinition.html#end--)

Answer (score -2):

end() will take care end of any type of camel Component, whereas endChoice() is specific to end the the choice Component.

Comment: Maybe I tell nonsense now, but from my experience endChoice doesn't close the whole choice block. It closes every when block. Look at the example of http://camel.apache.org/why-can-i-not-use-when-or-otherwise-in-a-java-camel-route.html, in the last code block you see the endChoice before the otherwise block.